# Como editar um tema instalado no vscode no Linux

Tags: css, json, visual-studio-code

Instalei recentemente o vscode e instalei o tema **Hail Theme**, porém gostaria de alterar a cor do menu. Por ex.: quando estou no editor, o menu fica dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém gostaria que ele ficasse com a cor dele ativo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Customizar o Tema eu não sei, mas nos seus Settings vc pode incluir uma cor padrão, ela vai ficar valendo para qq tema, mas como é algo que não se muda a toda hora, vc pode trocar depois se resolver usar outro tema etc...

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "list.activeSelectionBackground": "#0f0",
},
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso tenha dúvida, para abrir os Settings vc pode ir direto aqui, conforme imagem, ai vc coloca o código lá Salva e pronto!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Perfeito Hugo. Alterei apenas o comando colocando esse `"list.inactiveSelectionBackground": "#094771"`. Muito obrigado mais uma vez e para somar com o seu post, usei esse link para conhecer melhor os comandos que você mencionou. https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color

Comment: @Fox.11 cara nem sabia que tinha isso especificado na Documentação oficial rss. Mas fica ai como referência! Boa dica!